# Элегантный способ получить остаток от деления от единицы до делителя?

Tags: sql, oracle

При обычном делении:

```
SELECT mod(6,3) a FROM dual;
```

Мы получим ноль. Если делить будем не 6, а 5 или 4, то получим 2 или 1 соотвественно.

Есть ли красивый способ получить вместо нуля - делитель (3)?

Как вариант:

```
SELECT case when mod(6,3) = 0 then 3 else mod(6,3) end a FROM dual;
```

Но такая конструкция смотрится слишком громоздко, да и деление приходится выполнять дважды.

Comment: mod(6 - 1, 3) + 1

Comment: @EzikBro действительно

Comment: @EzikBro, mod(-6-1,3)+1 == 0

Comment: @TigerTV.ru ну очевидно, что для отрицательных чисел операция мод работает не так, как ожидается. Обычно непонятки начинаются с -1, но у меня уже с нуля. В прочем, не вижу в этом большой проблемы.

Comment: @EzikBro, проблемы нет, просто я думал у вас есть еще трюк для такого варианта.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru я не уверен, как именно работает mod для отрицательных чисел тут и, если честно, разбираться не хочу в данный момент. А вообще трюки конечно есть. Как минимум, можно прибавлять условное 2^30 к каждому N вместо вычитания 1. Тогда оно будет корректно работать для промежутка (-2^30; 2^30), а не для (0; 2^31). Хотя я не уверен, какой тип используется тут, так что возможно степени можно и увеличить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложенное уважаемым [@EzikBro в комментариии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1241962/%d0%ad%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f#comment2179684_1241962)  решение это [остаток от деления со смещением (modulo with offset)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Modulo_with_offset). Отличный способ генерировать подпоследователности начиная с 1-цы:

```
select rn,
    mod (rn, 3) mod,
    mod (rn - 1, 3) + 1 subseq
from (
    select rownum rn from dual connect by level<=9);

        RN        MOD     SUBSEQ
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         2          2          2
         3          0          3
         4          1          1
         5          2          2
         6          0          3
         7          1          1
         8          2          2
         9          0          3
```